# android - application displaying videos

Tags: android, resources, video

how do i display videos retrieved from resources in my android application ?

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.vid);
mp.start();
```

i have placed a vid.3gp file in my res/raw folder..

i am getting NullPointerException.. what changes do i need to make

why so??

do we need something called as Surface Holder or something similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) you should be able to play video

Comment: i have posted the code below..
can u help me out where am i going wrong?